# Neovim - changing keymaps on his own

Tags: plugins, neovim, keymaps

For two weeks know I am trying to switch to neovim as main development tool.
I added bunch of plugins and some custom keymaps.

Now when I use neovim sometimes what he will do is switch keymaps in terms

letter s -> would be action X
letter shift-s, S -> would be action Y

and for some reason sometimes he would just switch those two

letter s -> would be action Y
letter shift-s, S -> would be action X

Funny thing is that when that switch happen, I can go to some other window, like for example to browser ( I focus browser window), then come back to neovim and keymaps are now in initial state.

What could be the cause of this ?

EDIT
So sorry for this question -> problem was I left CAPSLOCK turned on

Comment: Can you check the result of `:map s` and `:map S` when this happens? I've never heard of this problem in 6 years of using neovim.

Comment: Will do, when it happens.  Is there some native functionality of vim/neovim to do those switchers or it is something outisde of neovim that affects it

Comment: I am so sorry. I dont know what to say. What happens is that my CAPSLOCK stays on, that is what happens. I am ashamed, that I didnt think of that.

Comment: I recommend swapping Caps Lock with Esc or Ctrl using key remappers such as Kmonad and autohotkey. You'll frequently need these keys in the terminal/Vim, and nobody need Caps Lock anyway.

Comment: Interesting, will try that tnx